# How to check if a struct field value exists in another struct field

Tags: go, data-structures, struct, iteration

```
type Bundle struct {
    Name    string   `bson:"name" json:"name"`
    Choices []string `bson:"choices" json:"choices"`
}

type Event struct {
    ID          bson.ObjectId   `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"_id,omitempty"` 
    Bundle      []Bundle        `bson:"bundle" json:"bundle"`
}

type AttendeeBundle struct {
    Name    string `bson:"name" json:"name"`
    Details string `bson:"details" json:"details"`
}

type Attendees struct {
    ID          bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"_id,omitempty"`
    Bundle      []AttendeeBundle      `bson:"bundle" json:"bundle"`
}
```

I am building an event registration platform. The Event contains a Bundle field where the Attendee can choose from.  Eg. T-shirt with various of size or color.

So upon registration, I want to make sure the attendee choice the correct bundle from the corresponding event.

I know can iterate for both attendee and event, something like this:

```
for _ , attendeebundle := range Attendees.Bundle {      
            for _, eventbundle := range Event.Bundle{
                //comparing attendee bundle and event bundle
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I think this too redundant, is there any other more elegant/effective ways to do this?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the loop as such, but you could perhaps create a custom type that is essentially a map, using the Bundle.ID value as key. You might need to write a custom `GetBSON` and `SetBSON` functions so you can marshal it into a slice if you want.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, I didn't know we can write custom unmarshal, thanks for the info!

Comment: Wait, was that the answer you're looking for?

Comment: Not exactly, but it is very useful info for me. I might need this in the future.